# Built-in WPF IValueConverters

Tags: wpf, converters

Ok, it was a nice surprise (after writing it several times) to find that there already is a **BooleanToVisibilityConverter** in *System.Windows.Controls* namespace.

Probably there are more such hidden time-savers.

Anyone got some?

Answer (score 106):

I did a quick trawl using the Object Browser and this is what I have.

Derived from `IValueConverter`:

> [`System.Windows.Controls.AlternationConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.alternationconverter.aspx)
>   [`System.Windows.Controls.BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx)
>   [`System.Windows.Documents.ZoomPercentageConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.zoompercentageconverter.aspx)
>   [`System.Windows.Navigation.JournalEntryListConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.journalentrylistconverter.aspx)
>
> `Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Converters.CurrencyConverter`
>   `Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Converters.DateTimeToStringConverter`
>   `Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Converters.GreaterThanZeroConverter`
>   `Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Converters.IndexToOddConverter`
>   `Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Converters.IntAdditionConverter`
>   `Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Converters.InverseBooleanConverter`
>   `Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Converters.LevelToOpacityConverter`
>   `Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Converters.MultimodalResultConverter`
>   `Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Converters.NegativeDoubleConverter`
>   `Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Converters.NullToBooleanConverter`
>   `Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Converters.SourceDataConverter`
>   `Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Converters.StringFormatConverter`
>   `Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Converters.ThicknessConverter`
>   `Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Converters.TypeToBooleanConverter`
>   `Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Converters.TypeToVisibilityConverter`
>   `Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Converters.ValueToMaskedTextConverter`

Derived from `IMultiValueConverter`:

> [`System.Windows.Controls.BorderGapMaskConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.bordergapmaskconverter.aspx)
>   [`System.Windows.Navigation.JournalEntryUnifiedViewConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.journalentryunifiedviewconverter.aspx)
>   [`System.Windows.Controls.MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuscrollingvisibilityconverter.aspx)
>
> [`Microsoft.Windows.Themes.ProgressBarBrushConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.themes.progressbarbrushconverter.aspx)
>   [`Microsoft.Windows.Themes.ProgressBarHighlightConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.themes.progressbarhighlightconverter.aspx)

Note the Xceed ones (no connection) are available free with their DataGrid. As well as those there's some clever stuff around like the [debugging converter](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/12/18/debugging-wpf-databinding/). I've also used [the last IValueConverter](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ScriptValueConverter.aspx) and I'm sure there's some further lambda function goodness to be found, too.

Comment: Hope you don't mind - just edited this by sorting the findings.  Nice to see what's inbuilt and what's Xceed specific.

Comment: I wonder which of them are still available in the Universal Windows Platform, for developing Windows 10 Universal Apps?

Comment: On MSDN, the Version Information section contains just ".NET Framework
-- Available since 3.0" for all the converters from Microsoft. Looks like Universal Windows Platform is not supported, @AHelloWorldDev. (E.g. System.Array states UWP support explicitly in Version Information section.)

Answer (score 29):

Before 3.5 SP1, an IValueConverter was required for string formatting.  Now, you can use the [StringFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat#System_Windows_Data_BindingBase_StringFormat) property on Binding to do this.

From the MSDN page:

```
<DataTemplate>
  <TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
      <MultiBinding  StringFormat="{}{0} -- Now only {1:C}!">
        <Binding Path="Description"/>
        <Binding Path="Price"/>
      </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
  </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: See this line for more examples: http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2008/05/19/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-stringformat.aspx

Comment: Also see this    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter(v=vs.110).aspx