# WPF Datagrid time field format hh:mm

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I use a WPF Toolkit Datagrid with a LINQ to SQL

```
       <my:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid2">
        <my:DataGrid.Columns>
            <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" MinWidth="80"
                                       Binding="{Binding Date, StringFormat=d}"
                                       CanUserSort="False"/>
            <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Time"  MinWidth="70" 
                                       Binding="{Binding Time}"
                                       CanUserSort="False" />
            <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" MinWidth="200"
                                       Binding="{Binding Description}" 
                                       CanUserSort="False"/>
        </my:DataGrid.Columns>
    </my:DataGrid>
```

Column `Time` is bound to a SQL Server table field of a `Time` datatype. Now time value on the Datagrid is displayed in a format **hh:mm:ss**.

How could I change a time represantation in the Time column of a Datagrid to **hh:mm**, removing seconds?

**EDIT**:
Using  `StringFormat=t` gives no result.

```
<my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Time"  MinWidth="70" 
                                       Binding="{Binding Time, StringFormat=t}"
                                       CanUserSort="False" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done using ValueConverter:

This can help:
[Built-in WPF IValueConverters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505397/built-in-wpf-ivalueconverters)

Answer (score 9):

```
<toolkit:DataGridTextColumn
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Width="SizeToCells"
                    Header="F. Resolución"
                    Binding="{Binding ColName, StringFormat=MM/dd/yyyy}" />
```

Answer (score 4):

without seconds

```
<toolkit:DataGridTextColumn
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Width="SizeToCells"
                    Header="F. Resolución"
                    Binding="{Binding ColName, StringFormat='MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm'}" />
```

with seconds

```
<toolkit:DataGridTextColumn
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Width="SizeToCells"
                    Header="F. Resolución"
                    Binding="{Binding ColName, StringFormat='MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}" />
```

here is only time with seconds:

```
<toolkit:DataGridTextColumn
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Width="SizeToCells"
                    Header="F. Resolución"
                    Binding="{Binding ColName, StringFormat='HH:mm:ss'}" />
```

Comment: another solution would be to convert your Timespan ("timespan2 in C# is equal to the "time" dataType in sql server) into DateTime and then try the above solution !

Comment: it worked for me, but how can I make ...StringFormat='HH:mm:ss'}" not present in hundred hours?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert your type from SqlDateTime to DateTime in order for the string format to work. Do this by casting your parameter to datetime. So for example when using c# to bring in your table.

```
dlEntry.StartTime = (DateTime)reader.GetSqlDateTime(3);
```

This will give you the ability to use the C# default converter for time.

```
<my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Time"  MinWidth="70" 
Binding="{Binding Time, StringFormat=t}"
CanUserSort="False" />
```